# How to extract specific String from rows of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is a part of my dataframe:

```
RefactoringDetail
"Pull Up Attribute  protected steps : int from class blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.PlayerAlgorithm to class blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Player"
"Pull Up Attribute  protected steps : int from class blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.PlayerAlgorithm to class blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Player"
"Pull Up Attribute  protected steps : int from class blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.PlayerAlgorithm to class blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Player"
"Move Class GameLogic.PlayerHuman moved to blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.PlayerHuman"
```

I need just this part:

```
 blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.PlayerAlgorithm 
 blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.PlayerAlgorithm 
 blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.PlayerAlgorithm 
 GameLogic.PlayerHuman
```

this is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('result_refactorings.csv', sep=';')
refactoring_details = df['RefactoringDetail']
print(refactoring_details)
a=refactoring_details.to_frame(name=None)
```

And then to extract what i need from the data frame I tried to use substring but it did not work

```
for elem in a:
  s = substring.substringByChar("elem", startChar="c", endChar="n")
```

I tried to extract the data after the String class and then I found that in the same row I have 2 Strings class butI need just the data after the first class

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you're perhaps searching for

```
df.RefactoringDetail.str.extract(r'lass ([^ ]*)')
```

Comment: thanks but in my dataframe i have rows like this :"Extract Method public isPlaceable(block Block, pt Point) : boolean extracted from public isPlaceable(block Block, corners ArrayList<Point>, pt Point) : boolean in class blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Map"  so it return NAN

Comment: I don't really get this issue. When I add this string to my test dataframe it works and returns `blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Map`

Comment: ok if i have this string also in my dataframe:    `"Extract Method public isPlaceable(block Block, pt Point) : boolean extracted from public isPlaceable(block Block, corners ArrayList<Point>, pt Point) : boolean in class blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Map"` what i should do and thanks to extract `blokusgame.mi.android.hazi.blokus.GameLogic.Map`